# How to limit UI when using Story Maps

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

I have been working with creating a story map on ArcGIS Online and I have been struggling to figure out how I can embed the webpage of my web scene to display a limited UI. When trying to embed the web scene into the story map, the display also includes my account logged in, and tools that I do not need.

I want to limit the UI so that the user of my story map gets only the map itself, and not additional tools, login options, and editing privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a blog post covering some tips:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/04/22/tips-embed-story-maps-websites/

The templates can be checked out in the git page as well if there are any other customization's you would like to make to the story map templates and you can host them in AGOL or on your own server.

https://github.com/Esri?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=story

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to figure out a solution to my issue. In order to limit the UI on an embedded web scene in ArcGIS Online story maps, all you have to do is add "**&ui=min**" to the end of the URL. This will still give them the ability to navigate through the scene, but it will limit their abilities to use unnecessary tools, to login, and to edit the scene.

It should be noted that this also takes away the ability to toggle layers. I have yet to figure out how to keep that ability, but I will post on it when I find out.